# C++: Identifying the type of the object

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm curious what constructs or language features, available in both the current C++ as well as in C++11, can be used to deduce the type of an object. An example:

```
class Base {
};

class DerivA
    : public Base {
};

class DerivB
    : public Base {
};

void foo(Base* obj) {
    // Identify if `obj` is a `DerivA` or a `DerivB`
}
```

This is an oversimplification. It would appear that rather than having a way to identify the type, the best solution is to have overloads of the function for the two derived types and do away with the base class.

My real use case is one where one class is not interested in the exact type of the object (ie. just needs an implementation of `Base`) and another class needs to know exactly what implementation of `Base` the first class is using.

This happens in a component-based game entity system. The base would be an `EntityState` and its derived types are `StandingState`, `DeadState`, etc. Class `Entity` is the one that only needs a generic `EntityState` object and class `EntityRepresentation` needs to know exactly what state the entity is in to decide whether to draw the "standing" animation or the "dead" animation, or whatever.

---

**Edit:** Of course, if possible, I'd like to implement the game in such a way that not even the entity representation needs to know the type of the entity state. If there's a way to do that, then I'd use it. :) I'll look into the visitor pattern.

Comment: This would seem like a good fit for [the Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: You can't do away with the Base class and still use polymorphism normally.

Comment: The obvious first attempt would be to add virtual functions, so you don't even need to know the exact type.

Comment: As Bo says, it is usually a point of doubt if you even _need_ to know the type explicitly; it's very likely that there will be a way to redesign your code to take advantage of runtime polymorphism.

Comment: The point of OO is that you should never do actions based on the type of the object. The object should know how to do the action. So rather than trying to detect the type you ask the object to the action foo() in C++ this is achieved via virtual functions.

Comment: @Martin I realize that. I haven't yet figured out how to do that in a simple enough manner or without compromising encapsulation.

Comment: @Martin It appears making states singletons is the only way I can have an "oo-correct" program and still have it be pretty simple. I'm hesitant to use singletons in this case, however. What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `dynamic_cast` for that:

```
if(DerivA * derivA = dynamic_cast<DerivA*>(obj)){
    // it is a DerivA
}
```

Comment: The classes he showed are not polymorphic, so use of `dynamic_cast` here invokes UB.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways:

If your classes are polymorphic use, `dynamic_cast`

or else you can use `typeid`

***Usage of typeid***

```
#include <typeinfo.h>


typeid(YourClass).name()
```

***Usage of `dynamic_cast`***

```
DerivA& dynamic_cast<DerivA&> (object);
DerivA* dynamic_cast<DerivA*> (object);
```

there must be least one virtual function in Base class to make dynamic_cast work or you will get compilation errors.

If you try to cast to pointer to a type that is not a type of actual object, the result of the cast will be NULL. For a similar situation in case of references the cast will throw a `bad_cast` exception.

Comment: Note that `typeid` will return the _exact_ type of the object. Whereas `dynamic_cast` will work even if the object is derived from `DerivA`. To put it another way, `dynamic_cast` will work if the type is in the object's hierarchy, while `typeid` tells you exactly and only what you have.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `<typeinfo>` part of the standard library (e.g. [see here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/).)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic_cast` to identify the type of the derived class object. For example, when you do: `DerivedA* p = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pBase);` if `p!=NULL` condition is satisfied then its an object of `DerivedA` type.

Comment: The classes he showed are not polymorphic, so use of `dynamic_cast` here invokes UB.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you described in the last paragraph can be solved using [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Have you tried it? It can solve the problem without even knowing the type its operating on.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to most of the suggestions, I would not use RTTI directly (either typeinfo or dynamic_cast). There are different things that you can do:

1. add a function that provides the information you need to draw
2. use a double dispatch mechanism

The simplest solution is probably 1), just add a virtual method that will tell you in what state the object is, and use that to determine how to animate the object. The problem with this approach is that it requires adding methods to the State classes for each one of the things that will need it: animation, sound, movement calculations...

Using a form of double dispatch like the visitor pattern moves the complexity away from the State hierarchy into the visitors hierarchy, that must contain overloads for each different State (at all levels). The model in the application will be simpler, but usage of that model will become more cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your types have a virtual method in them, you *can* use real time type identification (RTTI) of C++ with things like dynamic_cast and typeid

However, a better design might be to implement virtual methods to hide the types completely.  For example:

```
class EntityState {
  virtual void Draw( Entity entity ) = 0;
  }

class DeadState : EntityState {
  virtual void Draw( Entity entity ) {
    //*** render the entity as dead
    }
  }

class AliveState : EntityState {
  virtual void Draw( Entity entity ) {
    //*** render the entity as alive!
    }
  }

class Entity {

  EntityState myEntityState;

  void Draw() {
    myEntityState.Draw( this );
    }
  }
```

Your entities now can be drawn as either dead or alive without any if-then-else or switch statement code which would need updated if you suddently wanted new states to be added to your entity.

Comment: Ideally, the state shouldn't know or care how and/or if the entity is represented on the screen. I'd like to keep it like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually better alternative than trying to query the type of the object would be to add a virtual function to the base class:

```
class Base { public: virtual int Animation() const=0; };
class DerivA : public Base { public: int Animation() const { return 0; } };
class DerivB : public Base { public: int Animation() const { return 1; } };
```

And then have all the different animations identified by that one integer, maybe having a non-modifiable array of animations:

```
Animation anim1, anim2, anim3;
Animation *array[5] = { &anim1, &anim2, &anim3 };
void foo(Base *b) {
   int animnum = b->Animation();
   Animation *anim = array[animnum];
   ...
 }
```

That's at least one way to make it work properly.

Comment: See the comment I left on [MerickOWA's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442576/c-identifying-the-type-of-the-object/6442721#6442721).

Comment: sure, but stuff that is different based on which state derived class you chose should be part of the class hierarchy of the state. If the mechanism for choosing this is somehow different, then use dynamic_cast instead.

Answer (score -1):

for inheritence, I would look into static_cast and dynamic_cast.  You can use these to determine if a an object is inherited from a class.

Comment: `static_cast` does not help here, and because the classes he showed are not polymorphic, use of `dynamic_cast` would invoke UB.